# Multiple currencies on woocommerce with auto-switching based on location

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, currency

Do you know of a plugin that allows for multiple currencies on woocommerce but automatically switches to the appropriate currency based on the person's location?

Also, in general regarding the multiple currencies that are out there, how to they cope with gateway conversions? For example, if I'm actually selling in GBPs but the currency is converted using a plugin on the fly, will that go through to paypal as paying in that currency or in my original GBPs? What if Paypal's conversion rates then mismatch the plugin's?

Would really appreciate someone shedding some light on this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE: The information below is outdated.**

You might want to take a look at [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) and [Currency Switcher for WooCommerce](http://aelia.co/shop/currency-switcher-woocommerce/).

I haven't done much testing on it personally, but [here's a thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/currency-switcher-not-working-with-this-plugin?replies=25) where the developer of the currency switcher plugin is discussing how it works well with the PayPal for Woo plugin.

Comment: Check also https://wpglobus.com/product/wpglobus-multi-currency/